# How to set a selected value in a dropdown list using Mustache.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, mustache

Is it possible to do this with Mustache.js?

```
var data = {"val":"3"},
    template = '<select>' +
                    '<option value="1">1</option>' +
                    '<option value="2">2</option>' +
                    '<option value="3">3</option>' +
                '</select>';

var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);

$(html).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `val` attribute doesn't work, because a `<select>` takes its value from the `<option>`s which have the `selected` attribute. I'm not very familar with Mustache, but this *should* work:

```
// snip...        
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
$(html)
    .find('option[value=3]').attr('selected', true)
    .end().appendTo('body');
```

I think that the template you're using is not idiomatic Mustache — it's too coarse grained; you're not actually *templating* anything. Something like this might be more Mustache-y:

```
var template = '<select>{{#options}}' +
                   '<option value="{{val}}" {{#sel}}selected{{/sel}}>' + 
                       '{{txt}}' + 
                   '</option>' + 
               '{{/options}}</select>',

    data = {options: [
        {val: 1, txt: 'uno'},
        {val: 2, txt: 'dos'},
        {val: 3, txt: 'tres', sel: true}
    ]};

var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);

$(html).appendTo('body');
```

***[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/MF4sq/)***

Comment: No problem. TBH, that's the first Mustache code I've ever written ...but I write a lot of JSP ;-)

Comment: Does this work with JSON array only? Etc. `"options":["val1", "val2"]`

Answer (score 13):

if you do not want to modify the array or DOM tree afterwards you can use a function:

```
var selval=3; // select 3
var template = '<select>{{#options}}' +
                   '<option value="{{val}}" {{selected}}>{{txt}}</option>' + 
               '{{/options}}</select>';
var data={
    options: [
        {val: 1, txt: 'one'},
        {val: 2, txt: 'two'},
        {val: 3, txt: 'three'}
    ],
    selected: function() {
         if (this.val==selval) return "selected";
         return "";
    }
};


var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
```

Comment: For this to work, you need to remove the `#` from the `{{#selected}}` variable part in the template, or it will throw an "unclosed section" error.

Comment: Also, there's a typo. In the first line you define `selvar`, but then, in the `selected` function, you reference it as `selval`.
Also, for me the problem is when `selval` is variable, not "static" as in your example. I mean, when it is in the `data` object. And, furthermore, it is an array (think of a `multiple` select).

Comment: shouldn't `selected` be an attribute of the `data` object rather than an element of `options`?

Answer (score 3):

I use this hack to keep it simple:

```
buildOptions = function(object) {
    for (var i in object) {
        object[i + '=' + object[i]] = true;
    }
    return object;
}
```

In this way, you can transform this kind of data:

```
{
    field1: 'abc',
    field2: 'xyz' 
}
```

With this kind of Mustache Template:

```
<select name="field1">
    <option {{#field1=abc}}selected{{/field1=abc}}>abc</option>
    <option {{#field1=def}}selected{{/field1=def}}>def</option>
    <option {{#field1=ghi}}selected{{/field1=ghi}}>ghi</option>
</select>
<select name="field2">
    <option {{#field2=uvw}}selected{{/field2=uvw}}>uvw</option>
    <option {{#field2=xyz}}selected{{/field2=xyz}}>xyz</option>
</select>
```

Like this:

```
html = Mustache.to_html(template, buildOptions(data));
```

Which still really easy to read! The only caveat is that you can't have a '.' in your values.

Answer (score 2):

I little bit late, I know, just for future reference:

```
<script>

var templates = {
    'dropbox': '{{#options}}{{>option}}{{/options}}',
    'option': '<option value="{{value}}"{{#selected}} selected="selected"{{/selected}}>{{text}}</option>'
};

var data = {
    'options': [
        { 'value': '1', 'text': 'One' },
        { 'value': '2', 'text': 'Two', 'selected': true },
        { 'value': '3', 'text': 'Three' }
    ]
};

$('#number').append(Mustache.render(templates.dropbox, data, templates));

</script>

<select id='number' name='number'>
    <option value="0">Choose a number</option>
</select>
```