# IE error with script tag in template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js, mustache

I have the following script tag inside my Handlebar/Mustache template :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".enable-checkbox").click(function(e) {
                if ($(this).parent().attr("for") == "Webpage") {
                    $('#Webpage').attr("value", $(this).is(":checked")); // Set true/false.                    
                }                    
                if ($(this).parent().attr("for") == "Unsubscribe") {
                    $('#Unsubscribe').attr("value", $(this).is(":checked"));
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and FF.
However, on IE - I get an error:

```
Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.
```

After some research I figured out that the above error is due to the script tag my template. If I remove the script tag, it works in IE.

Can anyone suggest a way to get this working in IE?

P.S: Moving the contents of the script tag into the outer/main page that loads this script is not an option.

Comment: is the script inbetween <body> tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create templates in your JavaScript directly (without the need for a script tag)

```
App.templates = {

    template1: "{{#stooges}}" +
               "<b>{{name}}</b>" +
               "{{/stooges}}",

    template2: "{{#shows}}" +
               "<b>{{title}}</b>" +
               "{{/shows}}"

};
```

And refer to your template like so:

```
var output = Mustache.render(App.templates.template1, view);
```

Comment: The templates are already created and loaded as sections within a main page. Within these templates I am trying to initialize some values etc. It is working in FF and chrome but not in IE

Comment: Ah, maybe I misunderstood. You are saying that you actually have a script tag in your Mustache template?

Why not put that script in your script file? Why does it need to be in the template?

Comment: Yes. It needs to be within the template so that I can initialize some values. Eg. if I have a dropdown of say time values. I would like to get it initialize... something like   $("#ScheduledHour").val("{{this.ScheduledHour}}"); when the template loads.

Comment: Well, that structure is a little foreign to me. I'm surprised it works in Fx and Chrome.

Here's a post which covers setting the selected value on a drop-down list dynamically generated by Mustache:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518915/how-to-set-a-selected-value-in-a-dropdown-list-using-mustache-js